# Get all field values java program

Tags: java, reflection

I am building a Tetris game. I am currently debugging the game and in order to do this I need to see the values of all the variables and the variables variables and so on.  With reflection I can get all a classes fields by doing this:

```
try
{
    for(Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.get(this));
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{   
}
```

What I don't know how to get all the field values of each field object.

Comment: For debugging, use a debugger, which will allow you to step through the code line by line and view all the variables and objects recursively. System.out.println is the poor man's debugger.

Comment: I guess that might work but what i am needing all the field values for is so that i can display a crash report to the screen

Comment: Not if you're running a service and want to be able to log status in production.

Comment: What do you mean by field values?

Comment: the values of all the variables in the program originating from the class where i call the method

Comment: You're already doing it for an object (this). Do the same thing recursively for every field of the object. Just make sure to avoid infinite loops in case a child object references its parent (or in any other case where you have a loop and not a tree). You can do that by storing every already visited object in a collection.

Comment: that is what i am trying to accomplish, but how do i get a fields fields

Comment: @JoshSobel: recursion is the answer. Look at Valeri Atamaniouk's answer

Comment: @KevinBowersox: you're welcome. What does SOB mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Create a set of reachable objects. You don't want to recursively traverse your object graph forever.
2. Print values for every object.

For the first one, you need to use something like `IdentityHashMap`:

```
import java.util.IdentityHashMap;

class MyObjectCache
{
    final IdentityHashSet objects = new IdentityHashSet ();
    ...
}
```

To traverse objects you can use recursive function (it is simpler, but has a stack restriction):

```
class MyObjectCache
{
     ....
     void registerObject(Object o)
     {
         if (objects.contains(o))
         {
             return;
         }

         objects.add(o);
         for(Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
         {
             field.setAccessible(true);
             registerObject(field.get(o));
         }
    }
    ...
}
```

And then you can start printing collected objects...

Comment: An IdentityHashSet is more appropriate. Also, getDeclaredFields() don't include the inherited fields. +1 though.

Comment: thanks for the advice i should have been able to do this myself